# How to make forked GORM v1 print full path logs?

Tags: go, logging, go-gorm

Screens:

- [Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH8Xf.png)
- [Earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9oxP.png)

We've had to fork https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm (gorm v1) because of database driver. And now gorm prints logs without full log path. You can see details in screenshots.

How can we make correct output from the gorm logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$GOPATH/src/your_git.com/test/gorm/utils.go

```
var goSrcRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(`jinzhu/gorm(@.*)?/.*.go`)
var goTestRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(`jinzhu/gorm(@.*)?/.*test.go`)
```

replace **jinzhu/gorm** with your own